# Set Visual Studio up as x64 only by default

Tags: c#

I don't ever want AnyCPU or x32 for any of my C# projects or solutions. Is there a way to enforce this in Visual Studio 2017 whenever a solution or project is created.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project template by creating a new project, configuring it how you want and then going to `Project > Export Template`

This will create a new project template that will be re-imported into Visual Studio so you can build projects off.

Comment: I think this only works for a single project type. What I need is a global setting applying to whichever project type I pick.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all templates here:

%Program Files (x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\{year}\{version}\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\

So it is possible to change anything you want according to your needs.